# Script to temporarily drop admin privileges

Tags: security, sudo, users, root

I am creating a [self-control tool](https://github.com/miheerdew/delayed-admin) for administrators. The script when run by an administrator, would voluntarily drop admin privileges. The administrator can regain admin privileges by running the script again but faces an intentional delay (of say 20 min).

What would be a good way to do this?

#### My solution

Let's say the administrator is called `my-admin`. My current solution is the following:

- Add a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` that allows `my-admin` to run a script called `/usr/local/bin/delayed-admin` as root.
- The script `/usr/local/bin/delayed-admin` does the following: If `my-admin` is a part of the `admin` group, it removes it from the group. And if `my-admin` is not in the `admin` group then it sleeps for 20min and then adds it to the `admin` group.

This seems to work, but I don't like the idea of messing with the sudoer file every time.

Answer (score 0):

I would exercise extreme caution with this as it would be seen as a major security vulnerability since anyone can potentially run this script and gain admin access to your system.

To provide an alternative around the sudoers and the suders.d configuration.
I would recommend having the script check to see if you are part of the admins group and just run a `chmod -aG admins my-admin` to add the account or a `gpasswd -d my-admin admins` to remove the account.

Comment: In my code, the permission to run the script (via sudoers) is only given to `my-admin`. So I think that is safe.

Comment: In your solution how does `my-admin` run the script once he/she has dropped privileges?

Comment: Exactly, you were saying in the first point fo your solution that you would have the script running as root. 

if you take a user away from sudo, they will no longer have any permission to be able to add their account back into the appropriate group. You would have to use another account that runs this script with sufficient permission to add the user back into a suitable group

Comment: The entry in the sudoers file *only* permits `my-admin` to run  `/usr/local/bin/delayed-admin` as root. This would work regardless of whether `my-admin` is in the `admin`/`sudo` group or not. He just has to have admin privileges when the sudoers file is written.

Comment: Potentially create another group and make this person a member of this group and have one entry in the sudoers file where the group members have permission to run this script.
this way you can add multiple people to that group which has permission to only run this script and then that script grants/drops the access you talk about.